# Magento extentions not loading in MAMP

Tags: php, magento

Hi I have a complete fresh build and fresh database from the production website and loaded everything in to MAMP but some of the extensions I can see on production not showing up in my local I tried permissions and .htaccess file but nothing Emptied cache as well re installed new etc

I usually do a GIT pull from production to get the latest and the database  is also newly imported

Comment: "some of the extensions I can see on production not showing up in my local" -- What does "not showing up mean"?

Comment: Means I loaded  the extension as described now in my Local where i Use MAMP the extensions is not showing on the admin or front end but soon I deploy using GIT it shows in admin and front end on production and then  the issue occurring since I cant test in local suddenly screws up production because it shows up on front end and admin I changed permissions but I cant figure out why a exact copy isnt showing exact the same results

Answer (score 1):

If the files are "showing up" in the folder structure but the extensions are not appearing in the site.  Make sure that

1. there is an appropriate file inside app/etc/modules for each extension
2. the module is set to "enable" inside the admin (System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced).
3. if the module is an admin module you may have to log out and log back in again.

Agree with Alan though, would help if you were more specific with regards to "not showing up" - this is just general advice.

Comment: (System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced) All enabled

Comment: In the modules config file ( app->etc->modules->Your_app_file.xml) is the active tag set to true?

Comment: Just running through some thoughts...on your local MAMP are you viewing the site in a sub folder url, such as http://localhost/mysite/ - just wondering if there is something trying to path from root /.

Comment: Also, are you adjusting the site root (secure and non-secure) in the database on the local version?  You can find that in the core_config  table I think.

Comment: Might be that you do not have all the required php extensions running in your MAMP.  Rather depends on what the modules are using.  Anything reported in your magento error logs?

Comment: No MAMP has all the extensions I run several sites local for dev on that I seem to had issues with the offending sites database I removed all entries from  the database and then reloaded the site that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Seems I fixed it I deleted all database entries for the extensions which I had issues with then enabled the extension in etc/module and empty cache